# More precise bound for the maximin number of arrows pointing to a square when square grid is filled with arrows

Tags: co.combinatorics

The problem is as follows:

Suppose we fill each cell of a $n\times n$ square with one of the four arrows $\uparrow$, $\downarrow$, $\gets$, $\to$, like the following

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\downarrow & \downarrow & \gets\\
\hline
\to& \to& \uparrow\\
\hline
\to& \uparrow& \uparrow\\
\hline
\end{array}$

We define that entry $A$ (in $i$th column $j$th row) **points to** entry $B$ (in $k$th column $l$th row) if one of the four happens:

1. $A$ is filled with $\uparrow$ and $j> l$ and $i=k$
2. $A$ is filled with $\downarrow$ and $j< l$ and $i=k$
3. $A$ is filled with $\gets$ and $j= l$ and $i<k$
4. $A$ is filled with $\to$ and $j= l$ and $i>k$

(This is straightforward if you really fill them with arrows...)

For the example above, only the entry in first row, third column, points to the left upper corner. The right bottom corner entry points to the entry on the first row, third column and the entry on the second row, third column.

Let $r(n)$ be the maximum number such that there is a filling method such that every entry is pointed to by at least $r(n)$ other entries.

Now we have a bound $\frac{2}{3}n+O(1)\le r(n)\le \frac{5}{6}n+O(1)$

(update: now $ r(n)\le \frac{3}{4}n+O(1)$)

(update2: now $ r(n)\le (\sqrt{3}-1)n+O(1)$)

(update3: now $ r(n)\le n/\sqrt{2}+O(1)$)

The lower bound is obtained by the following construction:

[image: lower bound]

We first split the grid into the central $n/3\times n/3$ square surrounded by four regions as drawn. The red region is filled with $\to$, the green region is filled with $\downarrow$, The blue region is filled with $\gets$, the purple region is filled with $\uparrow$. The central square can be filled with anything. One can prove that every entry is pointed to by $\frac{2}{3}n+O(1)$ other entries.

On the other hand, counting the total number of entries one entry can point to, there are at most $\frac{5}{6}n^3+O(n^2)$ pairs (entry 1, entry 2) such that entry 1 points to entry 2. So, in average, an entry is pointed to by at most $5/6\; n+O(1)$ other entries.

Now, the question is: can the lower bound $2/3$ be raised and $5/6$ the upper bound be made smaller? I believe $2/3$ can be raised a little bit (for example, $0.01$) since the central $n/3\times n/3$ is not filled. But can it be **substantially** increased?

Any improvement is welcome and appreciated, even minor improvement with $2/3$ is welcome.

Update: a friend of mine gave me an $3/4\; n+O(1)$ upper bound. He considered the square connected the midpoints, where there are $2n$ entries. The entries inside the square point to at most one entry on the square, and the entries outside the square point to at most two. Thus, the number of entry points to the other entries is at most $1/2n^2+2\times 1/2n^2+O(n)=3/2n^2+O(n)$, and since there are $3n$ entries, averagely, one of the entries has at most $3n/4+O(1)$ entries points to it.

Update 2: That friend suggested another way: choose these entries in green
[image]

The green line four corners are of length $(\sqrt{3}-1)n/2$ entries. Using the similar argument above we can get $(\sqrt{3}-1)n+O(1)$ upper bound.

Update 3:
[image] That friend, again, suggested a  way: choose these entries in green, the lengths of the green lines in the four corners are $\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}n$ (they are the diagonal of the square of side length $\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}n$) and the central green square has diagonal length $(2-\sqrt{2})n$ These entries on the central square we give them a weight of $1/2$. So all the entries in the outside four triangles will point to weight two entries, the entries inside the central square will point to weight $1/2$ (one entry on the central square) and the rest will point to weight $1$ (two entries on the corner green lines, or two entries on the central square.) So the total weight of pointing will be $n^2+O(n)$. The total weight of green entries is $\sqrt{2} n+O(1)$, and by average, the number of entries pointed to a certain entry is at most $n/\sqrt{2}+O(1)$, so there must be one entry pointed by at most other $n/\sqrt{2}+O(1)$ entries.

Comment: I have improved the wording at some places to make it clearer. But I still have a hard time to understand your upper bounds (though I guess they are correct). What do you mean by "the square connected the midpoints" and by "The green line four corners are of length $(\sqrt{3}-1)n/2$ entries"?

Comment: @Wolfgang The square connect to the midpoints is the square that connect to four midpoints of four sides of the big square, in a total of $2n$ entries. The green corners of length $(\sqrt{3}-1)n$ entries means those green lines on those four corners are kind of diagonals of $(\sqrt{3}-1)n$ square... sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower bound can be substantially improved to $(1/\sqrt{2}-o(1))n$.

The proof goes in three parts: first a continuous analogue, then an LP analogue, and at last, the original problem.

### The continuous analogue

The continuous analogue of the original problem can be stated as follows:

Let $U,D,R,L$ be Borel functions on $[0,1]\times [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ satisfying $U+D+R+L=1$ and for every $(x,y) \in [0,1]\times [0,1]$, the value $\underset{0}{\overset{y}{\int}}U(x,t)dt+\underset{y}{\overset{1}{\int}}D(x,t)dt+\underset{0}{\overset{x}{\int}}R(t,y)dt+\underset{x}{\overset{1}{\int}}L(t,y)dt$ is at least $1/\sqrt2$.

Here $U,D,R,L$ are "densities of the up, down, right and left arrows", the first condition says that the "densities" at every point should add up to $1$, and the second condition says that every point should have at least a "mass" of $1/\sqrt{2}$ pointing to it.

The solution is as follows: Let $U$ be the function shown below.

[image]

The numbers surrounding the square are coordinates, and the numbers inside the square are the values of the function $U$.

The value $0$ is taken whenever $y \geq \frac12$.

When $y < \frac12 $, the value $\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{4}$ is taken in the two side triangles, and the value $\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{4}$ is taken in the lower triangle, and the value $\frac{1}{2}$ is taken otherwise (i.e. crossing dotted lines does not change the value of $U$). The top vertex of the lower triangle has coordinates $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2})$, making the function $U$ left-right symmetric.

The functions $D, L, R$ are defined by their respective rotations of $U$, i.e. $D(x,y)=U(x,1-y)$, $R(x,y)=U(y,x)$ and $L(x,y)=R(1-x,y)$. It is easy to see that $U+D+L+R=1$.

Let $U^*(x,y)=\underset{0}{\overset{y}{\int}}U(x,t)dt$, i.e. the "mass" of up arrows pointing to $(x,y)$. Define the functions $D^*, L^*$ and $R^*$ in similar manners. Then the original problem reduces to studying the minimum of $U^*+D^*+R^*+L^*$.

The function $U^*$ is piecewise linear, and so is $U^*+D^*+R^*+L^*$.

The function $U^*+D^*+R^*+L^*$ is plotted below:

[image]

The numbers at the vertices represents the value of the function at that point. It does not matter whether they are in the square or not.

As the function is piecewise linear in every region, the function is determined by the numbers at the vertices. So it has minimum value $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Thus the continuous problem is solved.

### The LP analogue

Let $U',D',R',L'$ be $N\times N$ arrays with indices from $1$ to $N$ whose elements are in $[0,1]$. Now the respective value needed to be studied for the cell $(p,q)$ is $\underset{t=1}{\overset{q-1}{\sum}}U_{p,t}'+\underset{t=q+1}{\overset{N}{\sum}}D'_{p,t}+\underset{t=1}{\overset{p-1}{\sum}}R'_{t,q}+\underset{t=p+1}{\overset{N}{\sum}}L'_{t,q}$. This is the linear programming analogue of the original problem as noted by RobPratt.

The continuous problem provides a way to (approximately) solve the LP problem: Let $U_{p,q}'$ be the average of $U$ in $[\frac{p-1}{N},\frac{p}{N}] \times [\frac{q-1}{N},\frac{q}{N}]$ and define $D', R'$ and $L'$ similarly. Under such an assignment, the value for the cell $(p,q)$ is at least $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}N-C$ where $C$ is a constant independent with $N,p$ and $q$.

The arrays should be written in the order where $p$ goes from left to right, and $q$ goes from down to up. Only in such order can the meanings of $U', D', R'$ and $L'$ be retained.

### The original problem

This is just a slight paraphrase of my comment in RobPratt's answer:

"Actually LP solutions serve as lower bounds. If we have a LP solution for $N \times N$ whose value is $K$, we can generate random arrow fillings on a $MN \times MN$ that matches the LP value arbitrarily close for sufficiently large $M$.

Dissect the $MN \times MN$ square into $N^2$ $M \times M$ sub-squares, corresponding to cells of the $N \times N$ LP solution. In a sub-square, let the directions of the cells be i.i.d. random variables with P(the arrow in the cell points at direction $x$) ($x\in\{\uparrow, \downarrow, \leftarrow, \rightarrow\}$) at least the value of the direction $x$ in the LP solution. Then as $M \rightarrow \infty$, it's asymptotically almost surely that every cell in the $MN \times MN$ square is pointed by at least $M(K-\epsilon)$ arrows, for any fixed $\epsilon>0$."

Taking into consideration that $K=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}n-O(1)$, we have proved that for every $\epsilon>0$ and sufficiently large $n$, there exists genuine solutions where every cell is pointed by at least $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\epsilon)n$ arrows. (The divisibility issues are immaterial for any positive $\epsilon$.)

Hence $(1/\sqrt{2}-o(1))n$.

### Discussion

By using [dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) techniques, it may be possible to get a solution directly from the continuous analogue, skipping over the LP analogue, that has every cell pointed by at least $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}n-c$ arrows for a fixed constant $c>0$. But I have no references about the mathematical properties of dithering, so I do not know how to work out a proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since what we need is this kind of construction!

Answer (score 10):

I used integer linear programming (in SAS) to compute the exact values for $n\in\{2,\dots,50\}$, and they match https://oeis.org/A248183.  Let $C_{i,j,d} \subseteq [n] \times [n]$ be the set of cells that can point to cell $(i,j)$ via direction $d$.  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,j,d}$ indicate whether the arrow in cell $(i,j)$ points in direction $d$, and let $z$ represent the smallest number of arrows pointing to a cell.  The problem is to maximize $z$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_d x_{i,j,d} &= 1 &&\text{for all $(i,j)$} \tag1\\
z &\le \sum_{(u,v) \in C_{i,j,d}} x_{u,v,d} && \text{for all $(i,j)$} \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ chooses exactly one arrow per cell.  Constraint $(2)$ enforces the maximin objective.

Figure 1 shows an optimal solution for $n=50$, with $r(50)=34$.  Maybe it will suggest a pattern for general $n$.
[image]

Restricting U to the bottom half and D to the top half does not change the optimal values for $n\le 50$.  For example, see Figure 2:
[image]

Nor does further restricting L to the right half and R to the left half.  For example, see Figure 3:
[image]

For even $n \le 50$, the optimal values still do not change if you further restrict each direction to appear $n^2/4$ times.  For example, see Figure 4:
[image]

Forcing horizontal and vertical symmetry, and forcing triangle with side length $10$ ($>10$ loses optimality), as suggested by @Wolfgang, but *not* forcing $n^2/4$ arrows per direction.  See Figure 5:
[image]

Forcing diagonal symmetry loses optimality.

I also tried forcing horizontal and vertical symmetry, $r(50)=34$, and minimizing the number of D (hence U).  The minimum is at most $192$, as shown in Figure 6:
[image]

With horizontal and vertical symmetry and $r(64)=44$, the minimum number of D (hence U) is $328$, as shown in Figure 7:
[image]

I solved the LP relaxation for $n=50$ with no restrictions and got objective value $34+6/7$.  The resulting optimal solution is not unique.  Figure 8 shows a plot where the color is determined by a fractional value $\ge 1/2$ (gray if the largest fractional value is $< 1/2$):
[image]

Figure 9 shows a heat map of the fractional assignments of cell to direction:
[image]

Figure 10 shows a heat map of the number of arrows pointing to each cell for an optimal LP solution with no restrictions:
[image]

Figure 11 shows a heat map of the number of arrows pointing to each cell for an optimal ILP solution with no restrictions:
[image]

Figure 12 shows a solution for $n=50$ where each cell has the minimum number $34$ of arrows pointing to it:
[image]

Comment: So... A248183 suggested $\sqrt{2}/2$ asymptotic... which is really close to the upper bound $\sqrt{3}-1$. This suggested some mixed pattern though

Comment: Good news: That friend of mine suggested a $\sqrt 2/2$ upper bound, which, If your hypothesis (the exact number somewhat matches the sequence you gave me) is correct and we can construct using the pattern, this upper bound and lower bound matches.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can I ask you to do me a favor... It seems that the construction has a central square boundary and there seem to be vague boundary on the four corners... Just like the location of the green entries in the proof of $n/\sqrt 2$. If you can give an asymptotic construction of $n/\sqrt 2$ based on your findings, I will really appreciate you for your work... Thank you so much for your work in advance!

Comment: Is there a solution with $D_4$ or maybe even $D_8$ symmetry?

Comment: For the last pattern, at the top in the middle there are 2 more or less "homogeneous" right triangles of sides n/4 (a red one to the left and a blue one to the right), likewise for the other sides of the big square (the two purple triangles are quite well visible, too). It might be worth to add that constraint, i.e. fix the arrows in those 8 triangles. The rest may group together (or be groupable together) in stripes forming diamonds around the center (for diamond sides $>n/(2\sqrt{2})$ only partial, because overlapped/"overwritten" by the 8 small triangles). (to be cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) If so, running the process several times may show which stripe widths are best suited for an optimal pattern, *before* starting tedious calculations. :)

Comment: I suggest some way: If we can allow one entry be "half right, half down" or so on, would the optimality change? because if $n$ go to $2n$, it can split into four and two of them going right, two of them going down, and so on. The ILP can be done with LP somewhat...

Comment: This is now http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St001767 (except that my code is apparently much worse than yours).

Comment: Thank you for trying! What a pity it doesn't work, at least not with as big as $n/4$. BTW note the interesting optical effect: green and purple spots in a red environment seem much darker than in a blue environment! :) OTOH forcing symmetry is a good idea. You might try to add diagonal symmetry too (it's already pretty much there). And maybe enforcing small red resp. blue triangles in each corner. I start believing that this trial and error will eventually lead to a (certainly not THE) nice, describable optimal pattern.

Comment: Now that one (minimizing the number of D and U) looks extremely interesting...  including the stripes in the corners. If your CPU allows, it would be definitely worth to try similar constraints for bigger n. And it looks like another example of the intriguing fact that in combinatorics, sometimes the optimal solutions are not the most symmetric ones.

Comment: I am not sure whether we are going to do the experiments again... But I strongly suggest to transform the problem from ILP to LP... Piecewise constant construction won't produce any irrational numbers. To produce that square root, I think we may try at least, linear density...

Comment: @JetfiRex The problem is "linear", and after the experiments it seems even clearer that at least one of the optimal constructions will consist of diagonal "segments" of a colour. It won't be "piecewise constant" proportionally to $n$, maybe part of it will, but probably it will also contain factors like $\lfloor n\sqrt{2}\rfloor$. (and this is *not exactly* proportional to $n$!) E.g. there may be stripes in the corners with a density half way between 1 and 2, guess what?

Comment: @Wolfgang Currently we can't say anything about the mixed structure... Something looked as stripes may be a part of mixed density and they're close to each other  (For example, the density is kind of $f(x+y)$ or something.) I would not like to guess anything because the density has a square root of it and I think it may be from the integral of the linear function... and although i admit i tried (piecewise) linear density is because it Seem to be the simplest.

Comment: Actually LP solutions serve as lower bounds: If we have a fractional assignment for $N\times N$, we can generate random arrow fillings on a $MN\times MN$ square. Dissect the $MN\times MN$ square into $N^2$ $M\times M$ sub-squares, corresponding to cells of the $N\times N$ LP solution. In a sub-square, let the directions of the cells be i.i.d random variables with P(pointing at direction x) (x∈{↑, ↓, ←, →}) at least the quantity of the direction x in the LP solution. Then as $M \rightarrow \infty$, the value on $MN \times MN$ almost surely matches the LP value with $o(n)$ error.

Comment: The comment above shows we have $(\frac{34+6/7}{50}-o(1))n$ solutions. 
On the other hand, is this LP solution the unique best solution of the LP? I have also tried LP relaxations and get similar values (approximately $\sqrt \frac 1 2 -\frac {1}{2n}$ for $n \times n$, $0.69710...$ for $n=50$, compared to your $0.69714...$) but my solutions are messy, like the first picture in your answer.  It may also be helpful if you can share your LP solver and the formulation of the problem in it.

Comment: I looked at the analogous problem for a triangular region, which is probably much easier to analyse.  Here the optimal values for side length $1$ to $26$ are $0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10$.

Comment: I was thinking again about averages. In the construction of my answer, we have avg/min=13/12. I suppose that in your scenarios this ratio is much tighter, i.e. closer to 1. But are there cells getting several more hits than the minimum number? If so, it would be nice to know where they tend to be (center? maybe some preferred regions?), so if you could provide heat maps for each scenario, that might give new insights about which regions are more/less "critical" wrt to the general minimum of hits. Maybe some (roughly how many?) cells can even be modified without affecting the minimum?

Comment: Thank you for the heat maps! But the first (symmetric) one should have the scale from 34 to about 44, if each integer gets a different colour, shouldn't it? I suppose this one belongs to your solution above "if you further restrict each direction to appear $n^2/4$ times...", right?

Comment: Would you mind labelling your diagrams with a, b, c... to refer more easily?

Comment: @Wolfgang I named them Figure 1 through 11 just now.

Comment: Thank you for that, and sorry for bothering you again - these heat maps just suggest to me new directions to search. What about an optimal solution, in which the minimum (i.e. 34 here) is achieved for as many cells as possible? And then the contrary, for as few cells as possible, which may reveal new patterns again? I also see that fig. 9 and 10, though not related, feature almost the same triangles on the borders, with a slope clearly $\ne1$. So this region seems to play an important role. What then about optimal solutions where the *maximum* of hits of a cell is as low (or high) as possible?

Comment: Figure 9 and 10 gives the pattern that is shown in the proof... that is beautiful, but... I hope to see there a construction (not only the calculation result) for the concrete bound soon...

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have thought that such a strong constraint is possible! Now intuitively, the more constraints, the more interesting patterns show up (provided of course that a solution exists), and if you enforce moreover vertical and horizontal symmetry, a solution still should exist, probably taking more time to complete the algorithm, but definitely worth it. And BTW, have you noticed that the pattern is not all too far away from figures 6 and 7? So...

Comment: Imposing symmetry and $34$ arrows pointing to each cell yields an infeasible problem.

Comment: So would it be more feasible if you start right away with a pattern like figure 6 or 7, maybe perturb it a bit, remove the symmetry condition and ask the algorithm to gently decrease the number of received hits of cells which have more than the minimum? BTW I would be curious to know how much CPU time it took typically e.g. for figure 6 or 7.

Answer (score 0):

The lower bound can be improved to $\frac{13n}{18}\approx .7222n$ by iterating your construction in the central $n/3\times n/3$ square, instead of filling it "with anything". In addition to the average $\frac{2n}3$ pointings coming to each square from "outside", we have rectangular regions, viz. $4$ like the brown one (area $\frac n3\times\frac{2n}9$) getting in average $\frac n9$ pointings from the brown region in the center, $4$ like the yellow ones (area $(\frac n3+\frac n9)\times\frac{2n}{27}$) getting in average $\frac n{27}$ pointings from the yellow region in the center, and so on.
This increases the average by a geometric series summing to $4\cdot\frac{n}{72}$, which makes the minimum bound $\frac{2n}{3}+\frac{n}{18}=\frac{13n}{18}$.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but this does not help... I have thought about this before, trying to fill in the central space. However, you could check the $2/3n$th entry on the first row, which is pointed by $2/3n$ (and no more) entries. This question seeks for maximin, not the average...

Comment: Oh I see. I guess it is all the $O(1)$ which gave me the idea of combining "asymptotic" and "average". Where you talk about average, you are rather applying a pigeonhole principle.